# rails rspec render_template matcher

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have this projects controller brief action.

**projects_controller.rb**

```
def brief
    #@project before_filter_da ataniyor
    if @project.user_allowed_to_view_brief?(current_user)
      @brief_notes = @project.brief_notes.order(:id)
      @project_files = @project.project_files
      render :action => :written_brief if @project.project_type.brief_template == :written
    else
      render :action => :hidden_brief
    end
  end
```

And this is my **projects_controller_spec.rb** file

```
context 'get :brief' do 
    it 'should be loaded successfully' do 
      sign_in @creative      
      @project.stub(:user_allowed_to_view_brief?).with(@creative).and_return(false)
      get :brief, :id => @project.to_param
      response.should render_template("hidden_gallery")
    end
  end
```

and When I run this test, I encounter the error like that.

```
Failure/Error: response.should have_rendered("hidden_gallery")
       expecting <"hidden_gallery"> but rendering with <"shared/_project_title, shared/_project_header, shared/_project_buttons, shared/_messages, projects/_brief, projects/brief, shared/_header, shared/_footer, layouts/application">
     # ./spec/controllers/projects_controller_spec.rb:63:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Answer (score 4):

I think that the last line of your spec should instead read:

```
 response.should render_template("hidden_brief")
```